# easier bookmarklet development

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Here's how I make develop a bookmarklet: I write a javascript function, pass that to Bookmarklet Builder to make a bookmarklet, add the bookmarklet to my browser, load my test webpage, test the bookmarklet, and then something doesn't work, so I try to find what's wrong and change my javascript function accordingly and the tedious cycle starts again.

How can I make this cycle less tedious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the firebug console to develop and test your function, and turn it into a bookmarklet once you've got it working like you want to.

Answer (score 17):

These days I prefer to edit a file on my webserver, then load that using a bookmarklet.  For example:

```js
javascript:(function(){
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.src = 'http://hwi.ath.cx/javascript/wordcloud.js?dummy='
                     + Math.random();
    document.body.appendChild(newScript);
})();
```

The random parameter is useful for a script under development, to ensure the browser won't load an older version from its cache.

I find development with a text editor far preferable to the console, because I can take advantage of syntax highlighting, shortcut keys, and — you know — newlines.

Comment: These days the URL should probably be `//your.domain/path` so that it will use http or https depending on the current page. But beware, many well-secured sites will block scripts loaded from unknown sites (CSP). So this approach might not work so well in 2018, depending where you are using it.