# User script directory in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, userscripts

When I follow a link to a user script in Google Chrome (for example, https://gist.github.com/raw/1107277/cacd006f78ae9e02bb10a173e30092b0b56fb5e9/answers-6825715.user.js), where does the script get stored? If I make changes and save, will the script be updated when I refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the script gets stored in the ***Extensions*** folder at:

```
Windows XP:
C:\Documents and Settings\***{username}***\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Windows Vista:
C:\Users\***{username}***\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Windows 7:
C:\Users\***{username}***\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

You can change the folder by running Chrome with the `--user-data-dir=` option.

If you make changes to the script, they won't apply until the script is reloaded by Chrome.
To reload a script, either restart Chrome, or navigate to ***chrome://extensions/*** and do hit the ***Reload*** link, if it is available.

If the *Reload* link is not available, hit ***Disable***, then ***Enable*** for the changes to go into effect.
Note that changing the script's `@include`, `@exclude`, or `@match` directives will do nothing on already installed scripts.  The ***manifest.json*** file must be edited for that.

See ["Manually adding a Userscript to Google Chrome"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome/5259212#5259212) for more information.