# Automatic TOC in github-flavoured-markdown

Tags: github, markdown, tableofcontents

Is it possible to generate an automatic Table of Contents using [Github Flavoured Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/)?

Comment: If you use linux and dont want to install any additional software try [github-markdown-toc](https://github.com/ekalinin/github-markdown-toc) (only awk under the hood).

Comment: I am rendering multiple markdown files inside jade templates into html. So I need my TOC to contain more info than is found in one markdown file. My solution is to generate the TOC from the HTML code itself with the node.js library [`toc`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/toc)

Comment: I've created three different markdown TOC generators trying to "get it right", including marked-toc listed above. [markdown-toc](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/markdown-toc) is my favorite, it's uses a real markdown parser ([remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) that follows the [commonmark](commonmark.org) spec, allows TOCs to be updated, has a CLI and API, and is now used on thousands of projects

Answer (score 158, accepted):

I created two options to generate a toc for github-flavored-markdown:

#### DocToc Command Line Tool ([source](https://github.com/thlorenz/doctoc)) requires [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Installation:

`npm install -g doctoc`

Usage:

`doctoc .` to add table of contents to all markdown files in the current and all sub directories.

#### <strike>DocToc WebApp</strike>

If you want to try it  online first, go to the [doctoc](http://doctoc.herokuapp.com/) site,
paste the link of the markdown page and it will generate a table of
content that you can insert at the top of your markdown file.

#### Github Wikis and Anchors

As Matthew Flaschen pointed out in the comments below, for its wiki pages GitHub previously didn't generate the anchors that `doctoc` depends on.

**UPDATE: However, they fixed [this issue](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/380).**

Comment: I developed GitHub Wikifier: A pre-commit Git Hook that will generate all the Table of Contents you will ever need. Just write your content, and let it take over. May be worth a check. https://github.com/kuroir/GitHub-Wikifier

Comment: It's a good starting point but it don't produce a standard code. Plus, have no working anchors.

Comment: the DocToc web app does not work. I used [markdown-toc](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/markdown-toc)

Comment: there is a very easy to set up action using doctoc: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/toc-generator

Answer (score 28):

GitHub Pages (which is basically a wrapper for Jekyll) [appears to use kramdown](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll.rb#L29), which [implements all of Maruku](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/parser/kramdown.html), and therefore has support for an [automatically generated table of contents](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/maruku.html#toc-generation) via a`toc` attribute:

```
* auto-gen TOC:
{:toc}
```

The first line just starts an unordered list and is actually thrown away.

This results in a nested set of unordered lists, using the headers in the document.

**Note:** this should work for GitHub Pages, not GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM) as used in comments or wiki pages. AFAIK a solution doesn't exist for that.

Comment: This doesn't work. It justs renders that text. Can you link a file which uses such a TOC?

Comment: Yep: http://maruku.rubyforge.org/maruku.md or https://raw.github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/gh-pages/index.md

Comment: Note that this is a Maruku feature, not Markdown per se, and probably not even GH Flavored Markdown. GH-pages does use Maruku though.

Comment: @KevinSuttle are you sure? Jekyll includes redcarpet but maruku still looks like the default (unless GH uses a different jekyll config) https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll.rb#L66

Comment: @BenScott It looks like your solution only works for github pages. Do you know of a solution for github wiki?

Comment: @reprogrammer no I don't know of anything for GFM as used in the wiki pages, which is unfortunate

Comment: Just tried this on GitHub pages with a Jekyll theme (that presumably now uses Kramdown), and it works fine. No option to set the heading levels, apart from excluding them with `{:.no_toc}` immediately beneath the heading to be excluded from the TOC.

Answer (score 16):

**Update March 2021: GitHub added an official workaround**

READMEs now show a ToC like this as you scroll down into them:

[image]

demo: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/tree/master/d

It does not render inside the document as I wanted for better Ctrl + F, but it is better than nothing.

Also also works for non-README as well now, e.g.: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/blob/master/md.md

They also added a repository setting to enable disable that. It's so weird, who would ever want to disable it? Under https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/settings Features:

> Table of contents
>
> Autogenerate table of contents for Markdown files in this repository. The table of contents will be displayed near the top of the file.

**Original answer**

It's not possible, except for the workarounds proposed.

I [proposed](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/215) Kramdown TOC extension and other possibilities to support@github.com and [Steven! Ragnarök](https://github.com/nuclearsandwich) replied with the usual:

> Thanks for the suggestion and links. I'll add it to our internal feature request list for the team to see.

Let's upvote this question until it happens.

Another workaround is to use Asciidoc instead of Markdown, [which does render TOCs](https://github.com/cirosantilli/test/blob/406832b1dd2be892bfea9cac2d90f5d466418b0d/adoc.adoc). I've moved to this approach for my content nowadays.

Comment: I would rather hope GFM will provide it some day. It is really a courius thing for me while SourceForge's Markdown has the syntax to generate this [TOC](https://sourceforge.net/adobe/tlf/wiki/markdown_syntax/#md_ex_toc1) by default.

Comment: It appears to be working for non-readme files now too.

Comment: Oh that's nice. I at least have minimal functionality with minimal markup and tools no matter if I work with GitHub or GitLab.

Answer (score 16):

If you edit Markdown files with Vim, you can try this plugin [vim-markdown-toc](https://github.com/mzlogin/vim-markdown-toc).

The usage is simple, just move your cursor to the place you want to append Table of Contents and run `:GenTocGFM`, done!

Screenshots:

[image: vim-markdown-toc]

Features:

1. Generate toc for Markdown files. (Support GitHub Flavored Markdown and Redcarpet)
2. Update existing toc.
3. Auto update toc on save.

Comment: make sure to find a common TOC style in case you collaborate on .md files and different editors/plugins are involved to not get changes on the TOC in every other commit. Possible additions to `~/.vimrc` for this: change list character with `let g:vmt_list_item_char = "-"`, include headings before TOC with `let g:vmt_include_headings_before = 1`. See [the docs options section](https://github.com/mzlogin/vim-markdown-toc#options) for more, e.g. how to change the fence text.

Answer (score 11):

It's not automatic, but it uses Notepad++ regular expressions:

Replace all first by the second (removes all lines not having headers)

```
^##(#?)(#?)(.*?)$(.|\r|\n)*?(?=^##|\z)
-\1\2 [\3](#\3)\n
```

Then (converts headers III to spaces)

```
-##
        -
```

Then (converts headers II to spaces)

```
-#
    -
```

Then (remove unused chars at the beginning and at the end of link title)

```
\[ *((?:(?![ .:#!\?;]*\])[^#])*)[ #:!\?;]*\]
[\1]
```

Then (convert last tokens lowercase and dash instead of spaces)

```
\]([^ \r\n]*) ([^\r\n ]*)
]\L\1-\2
```

Remove unused final pounds and initial dashes:

```
(?:()[-:;!\?#]+$|(\]#)-)
\1\2
```

Remove useless chars in links:

```
(\].*?)(?:\(|\))
\1
```

And finally add parenthesis around final links:

```
\](?!\()(.*?)$
\]\(\1\)
```

And voilà! You can even put this in a global macro if you repeat it enough time.

Answer (score 10):

A very convenient way to achieve a table of contents for a mardown file when working with Visual Studio Code is the extension [Markdown-TOC](https://github.com/AlanWalk/Markdown-TOC).

It can add a toc to existing markdown files and even keep the toc up-to-date on saving.

[image]

Comment: Another nice VS code plugin (great .md support with nice features including GitHub & GitLab flavored TOC) is [markdown-all-in-one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one).

Answer (score 8):

Github Flavored Markdown uses RedCarpet as their Markdown engine.
From the [RedCarpet repo](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#darling-i-packed-you-a-couple-renderers-for-lunch):

> :with_toc_data - add HTML anchors to each header in the output HTML,
>       to allow linking to each section.

It seems in that you'd need to get at the renderer level to set this flag, which isn't possible on Github obviously. However, the [latest update](https://github.com/blog/1173-github-pages-update) to Github Pages, it seems that automatic anchoring is turned on for headers, creating linkable headings. Not exactly what you want, but it might help you create a TOC for your doc a bit easier (albeit manually).

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to generate a webpage automatically with http://documentup.com/ from the `README.md` file. It's not creating a TOC, but for many it might solve the reason for wanting to create a TOC.

Another alternative to Documentup is Flatdoc: http://ricostacruz.com/flatdoc/

Answer (score 4):

Majority of other answers require to install some tool.
I found a quick and easy online solution **https://imthenachoman.github.io/nGitHubTOC.**

For any markdown input it generates table of content output.
You can specify minimum and maximum heading level.

The source code is located at https://github.com/imthenachoman/nGitHubTOC

Comment: lovin it. 200% agree with your "the lesser tool the better" approach

Comment: Liking this a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Gitdown](https://github.com/gajus/gitdown) is a markdown preprocessor for Github.

Using Gitdown you can:

- **Generate Table of Contents**
- Find dead URLs and Fragment Identifiers
- Include variables
- Include files
- Get file size
- Generate Badges
- Print Date
- Print information about the repository itself

Gitdown streamlines common tasks associated with maintaining a documentation page for a GitHub repository.

Using it is straightforward:

```js
var Gitdown = require('gitdown');

Gitdown
    // Gitdown flavored markdown.
    .read('.gitdown/README.md')
    // GitHub compatible markdown.
    .write('README.md');
```

You can either have it as a separate script or have it as part of the build script routine (such as [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)).

Answer (score 2):

Use [coryfklein/doctoc](https://github.com/coryfklein/doctoc), a fork of [thlorenz/doctoc](https://github.com/thlorenz/doctoc) that does not add "*generated with* [DocToc](http://doctoc.herokuapp.com/)" to every table of contents.

```
npm install -g coryfklein/doctoc
```

Answer (score 1):

My colleague @schmiedc and I have created [a GreaseMonkey script](http://tomancaklab.github.io/gfm-add-toc.user.js) that installs a new `TOC` button left of the `h1` button which uses the excellent `markdown-js` library to add/refresh a table of contents.

The advantage over solutions like doctoc is that it integrates into GitHub's wiki editor and does not need users to work on their command-line (and require users to install tools like `node.js`). In Chrome, it works by drag 'n dropping into the Extensions page, in Firefox you will need to install the GreaseMonkey extension.

It will work with plain markdown (i.e. it does not handle code blocks correctly, as that is a GitHub extension to markdown). Contributions welcome.

Comment: Thanks much! I had to use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259212/307454) to install it in Chrome, and it worked! What would it take to make your script to generate TOCs for normal markdown files in the github repo?

Answer (score 1):

This is a not a direct answer to this question as so many people have provided workarounds. I don't think generating a TOC has been officially supported by Github yet to-date. If you want GitHub to render a Table of Contents on their GFM preview pages automatically, please participate the discussion on the official [feature request issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/904).

Answer (score 1):

There's now a GitHub Action accomplishing this:

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/toc-generator

1. Specify location of TOC (option)
   e.g. `README.md`

```
<!-- START doctoc -->
<!-- END doctoc -->
```

2. Setup workflow
   e.g. `.github/workflows/toc.yml`

```
on: push
name: TOC Generator
jobs:
  generateTOC:
    name: TOC Generator
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: technote-space/toc-generator@v2
```

Comment: Excellent, this is very close to what I was looking for. I don't want to install a lot of extensions in more than one editor just to get a result which GitLab provides to me by using `[[_TOC_]]`. Now to get this working for the uninitiated, go to settings -> Actions -> Workflow permissions -> and enable **Read and write permissions**. Replace v2 with the current version, e.g. v4 at the time of writing. Want to use it on all Markdown files? Look at how `with:` is used in the examples and add `TARGET_PATHS: "*.md"`.

Answer (score 1):

> Shameless "borrow" of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249534/5299417).

You can do this with [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

```
pandoc -s --toc input.md -o input_toc.md
```

*Note: the order of the input and output files is important here.*

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's [not possible](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/904) using markdown syntax (see the ongoing [discussion at GitHub](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/215)), however you can use some external tools such as:

- Online [Table Of Content Generator](https://github.com/raychenon/play-table-of-contents) ([raychenon/play-table-of-contents](https://github.com/raychenon/play-table-of-contents))
- [arthurhammer/github-toc](https://github.com/arthurhammer/github-toc) - browser extension that adds a table of contents to GitHub repos

---

Alternatively use `AsciiDoc` instead (e.g. `README.adoc`), e.g.

```
:toc: macro
:toc-title:
:toclevels: 99
# Title

## A

### A2

## B

### B2
```

as suggested in this [comment](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/215#issuecomment-336328746). Check the demo [here](https://github.com/littlebits/react-popover).

Comment: The hosting of Online Table Of Content Generator (raychenon/play-table-of-contents) on  http://tableofcontent.eu" stopped due to costs of AWS.

Answer (score 0):

For **Github's Texteditor [Atom](https://atom.io/)** check out this awesome plugin (or "package" in Atom-lingo), which generates *"TOC (table of contents) of headlines from parsed markdown"* files:

**[markdown-toc](https://github.com/nok/markdown-toc)**

Once installed as Atom-package you can use the shortcut **`ctrl-alt-c`** to insert a TOC based on your markdown-doc-structure at the current cursor position...

**Screenshots:**

[image]

**Atom Keybindings**

markdown-toc gives you the following default key-bindings to control the plugin in Atom:

- `ctrl-alt-c` => create TOC at cursor position
- `ctrl-alt-u` => update TOC
- `ctrl-alt-r` => delete TOC

**Plugin Features** (from the project's README)

- Auto linking via  anchor tags, e.g.  `# A 1` → `#a-1`
- Depth control [1-6] with `depthFrom:1` and `depthTo:6`
- Enable or disable links with `withLinks:1`
- Refresh list on save with `updateOnSave:1`
- Use ordered list (1. ..., 2. ...) with `orderedList:0`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shell script I threw together today for this. Might need to tweak it for your needs, but it should be a good starting point.

````
cat README.md \
    | sed -e '/```/ r pf' -e '/```/,/```/d' \
    | grep "^#" \
    | tail -n +2 \
    | tr -d '`' \
    | sed 's/# \([a-zA-Z0-9`. -]\+\)/- [\1](#\L\1)/' \
    | awk -F'(' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if(i==2)gsub(" ","-",$i);}1' OFS='(' \
    | sed 's/^####/      /' \
    | sed 's/^###/    /' \
    | sed 's/^##/  /' \
    | sed 's/^#//'
````

If anyone knows a better way to do those final # replacements, please add a comment. I tried various things and wasn't happy with any, so I just brute forced it.

Answer (score 0):

*Update 2022-02*

In VSCode, check out extension "Markdown All in One". It will generate and update the TOC of markdown automatically.

1. Install Extension.
2. Place cursor at where you want to insert TOC.
3. Run command "Markdown All in One: Create Table of Contents"
4. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

GitHub will automatically create a table of contents in AsciiDoc pages. You can give it a try by (1) changing the page's type to `AsciiDoc`. Then (2) insert `:toc:` at the top of the document. Here's the result. I made [this demo repo](https://github.com/dogweather/github-wiki-toc-demo/wiki) to demonstrate it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created my own Table of Contents generator script for GitHub markdown in Python. I tried to cover all edge cases like underscores, inline code headers etc.

https://github.com/maksyche/github-md-toc-generator

Not perfect, but works for my projects.