# What happened to the TOC extension for ipython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm trying to install the great table of contents extension in a new computer. but I cant find it anymore. the only page [I do find](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions) does not explain how to install the extension on windows.

So.. How can I install it, and why is it not a part of the official Ipython notebook? I simply can't understand how people are getting along without it.

Comment: Lots has changed - see dreme's answer!

Comment: `pip3 install --user jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` then 
`jupyter contrib nbextension install --user` then Activate the table of content extension: `jupyter nbextension enable toc2/main`

Answer (score 7):

I've installed  [toc nbextension](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions) successfully with **Jupyter 4** (ie. ipython notebook 4) recently. 
In fact installing extension is easier than before :)

I post my solution here, may it help.

```
## download 
mkdir toc
cd toc
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/master/nbextensions/toc.js
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/master/nbextensions/toc.css

## install and enable
cd ..
jupyter-nbextension install --user toc
jupyter-nbextension enable toc/toc
```

A bit more explain:

`install` will copy `toc` to `~/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/`

`enable` will modify `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`.

You can check these two place to see what happened.

Note: we use `enable toc/toc` here is because `toc.js` is in `~/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/toc/`.
If you put `toc.js` and `toc.css` directly in `~/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/` then you should use `enable toc` here.

**Edit**

Sorry, I didn't notice the orginal problem is on windows. I'm not sure if it's same for windows jupyter, any report is welcome.

**Update**

Now the toc nbextension has been added into [this project](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions) which provide a collection of kinds of nbextensions. It's very easy to install and manage, worth to try!

Comment: The extension project works beautifully, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot tell you specific Windows advice, but think the key points should be platform independent:

1. Create a profile (either a default profile or a named one - you'll probably want default to start).
2. Locate where the profile is.
3. Add the `custom.js` file into the profile.
4. Edit the `custom.js` file to point to the notebook extension code.

In a bit more detail, setting up a profile is [covered in detail here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html#profiles) but for a default profile just go to the command line and enter

```
ipython profile
```

Next, locate where your profile is stored by typing *at the command line*

```
ipython locate
```

Call that `<profile_dir>`.

The rest follows the (Windows equivalent of!) the instructions on the link you have: underneath `<profile_dir>` navigate to (creating any directories that do not already exist)

```
<profile_dir>/static/custom/
```

and add the `custom.js` file as shown. Then edit the first line, where it has `"nbextensions/toc"` to point to the location where you have placed the `toc.js` file you have downloaded. This location is relative to the `<profile_dir>`; for me I have

```
<profile_dir>/static/custom/custom.js
<profile_dir>/static/custom/nbextensions/toc.js
<profile_dir>/static/custom/nbextensions/toc.css
```

and the first line of custom.js reads

```
require(["/static/custom/nbextensions/toc.js"], function (toc) {
```

Finally, note that this is with version 1.1.0 of the notebook - if you're using an earlier version I strongly suggest you upgrade before trying this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also find the official installation instructions at:

https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions

These instructions include curl commands for retrieving the toc.js and toc.css files from GitHub, which worked fine for me in a bash shell on linux Mint.

For Windows 7, I used a Git Shell (see http://msysgit.github.io/) to execute the curl commands

Answer (score 0):

[This IPython Notebook](https://github.com/ahambi/140824-TOC/tree/master) semi-automatically generates the files for minrk's table of contents in Windows. It does not use the 'curl'-commands or links, but writes the *.js and *.css files directly into your IPython Notebook-profile-directory.

There is a section in the notebook called **'What you need to do'** - follow it and have a nice floating table of contents : )

Here is an html version which already shows it: 
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/ahambi/140824-TOC/blob/master/A%20floating%20table%20of%20contents.htm