# Installing IPython Notebook table of contents

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to install the extension to generate automatic table of contents using header cells.

however, when I copy/paste

```
curl -L https://rawgithub.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/master/nbextensions/toc.js > $(ipython locate)/nbextensions/toc.js
```

into terminal, it says directory not found. The extension in question can be found [here](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions).

Comment: have you created the sym links ?

Comment: Sorry how do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happend to the TOC extension for ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188698/what-happend-to-the-toc-extension-for-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 2):

Install [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) by entering the following commands at the shell

```
pip install --user jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

Activate the table of content extension:

```
jupyter nbextension enable toc2/main
```

There are many other extensions available in this package.
Optionally you can install the jupyter notebook extension configurator (not needed)

```
pip install --user jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

This will make a configurator available at:

```
http://localhost:8888/nbextensions
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it worked for me using Ubuntu:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions.git

2. ln -s $(pwd)/extensions $(ipython locate)/extensions
   ln -s $(pwd)/nbextensions $(ipython locate)/nbextensions

3. curl -L https://rawgithub.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/master/nbextensions/gist.js > $(ipython locate)/nbextensions/gist.js

4. I use ubuntu so I  used the text editor from bash like so   gedit $(ipython locate profile)/static/custom/custom.js. 

5. I appended "IPython.load_extensions('gist');" to the bottom of  custom.js and saved the file.
```

If you want to install the Retina Figures extension follow the rest of the instructions [here](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/blob/master/README.md)

If you do are using Windows there is a tutorial [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) that shows both how to create sym links in Windows and Linux.

If you do not have git installed then download the zip file with this [link](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/archive/master.zip)

Answer (score 0):

[This IPython Notebook](https://github.com/ahambi/140824-TOC/tree/master) semi-automatically generates the files for minrk's table of contents in Windows (I guess one only needs to change

```
%%cmd- to %%bash magics
```

to make it work in Linux). It does not use the 'curl'-commands or links, but writes the *.js and *.css files directly into your IPython Notebook-profile-directory.

There is a section in the notebook called **'What you need to do'** - follow it and have a nice floating table of contents : )

Here is an html version which already shows it: 
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/ahambi/140824-TOC/blob/master/A%20floating%20table%20of%20contents.htm

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the repo and creating the sum links did not work for me.

While using ipython 1.1, I had to do the following:

1. Download the jquery-2.0.2.min.map, from [this link](https://github.com/davidfowl/SignalR.Lite/blob/master/SignalR.Lite/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.map) and copy it to $HOME/.ipython/profile_default/static/components/jquery/
2. Create sym link to nbextensions in the $HOME/.ipython/profile_default/static/
   ln -s ../../nbextensions nbextensions

The extension expects the section headings to be in separate cells. So, if one has a markdown cell with a few headings & sub-headings, it will not be recognised.

For ipython 2.2, you need to also download the min map files of backbone & underscore also.