# Simultaneously edit the same ipython notebook in two tabs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

As my ipython notebooks get larger, I find myself more and more frequently wanting to quickly move between two sections.  Since there is no split-window view, is there any way to edit the same notebook in two browser tabs simultaneously?  Naively it seems that you have to reload the notebook in the second window after making changes in the first.

I'd also be interested in any general workflow suggestions for this, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a perfect solution, but I use section headers and a floating table of contents to jump around to different sections. It's nice that it encourages me to make headings, although it's not super efficient. I use MinRK's extension to make the TOC ([here](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions)).

If you want to go the TOC route, you should look at the [How can I add a table of contents to an ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151450/how-can-i-add-a-table-of-contents-to-an-ipython-notebook) question. The answers there (currently) suggest either MinRK's extension to the notebook as I use, or a simple browser extension that can generate a TOC for any webpage.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.