# Is there a document map extension for Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, document

One of the main advantages of using Jupyter is the ability to code and document in the same time. Many times, I use headings and subheadings to group the code in a notebook. However, as the notebook gets longer, navigation becomes much harder.

It would be nice to have a document map in a separate (left) pane that keeps track of the markdown headings. Once a heading is selected in the document map, the respective section would appear in the main pane.

Is there an extension for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment on your question (low points) so if the answer is a bit off...

- I've found an extension that looks like what you need

  - src: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/toc2
  - Documentation: http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/toc2/README.html
- Another, not that good:
  (imho) https://github.com/captainsafia/notebook-toc

  ---

Possible duplicate of: [How can I add a table of contents to an ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151450/how-can-i-add-a-table-of-contents-to-an-ipython-notebook)

**EDIT**

### Install instructions:

Toc2 is included in: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

to install just TOC2 i did this:

```
pip3 install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable toc2/main
```

**EDIT 2**
How to display the TOC inside a notebook:  http://awesomescreenshot.com/0116cqvh5b

Comment: That is exactly what I want; Thanks. The installation instructions are, however, not so obvious. I'm not sure whether I can use the usual `jupyter nbextension install` command for this. Could you please show how to install the (first) extension?

Comment: Install instructions can be found on the documentation page: http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html. Glad i could help

Comment: to clarify this `toc2` is already  included `ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions repo by @JanSchulz` see git https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

Comment: Many thanks. I was initially trying to enable `toc2` instead of `toc2/main` (didn't check the update on the answer). I found the Nbextensions tab much more friendly and easier to tune specific options within the toc2. Answer accepted!