# How do I create some kind of table of content in GitHub wiki?

Tags: github, wiki

If you look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow

You'll notice there's a little "Content" section, if you click on one of the links, it will send you to a specific section on the page.

How do I do this in GitHub wiki?  With Markdown or whatever they use?

Comment: Related, but not exact duplicate, that goes into more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9721944/2291

Comment: Update March 2021 (almost 8 years later): GitHub can create automagically table of content for `README.md`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824119/6309).

Comment: Update Aug. 2021: GitHub can create automagically table of content of your ***wiki***! See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824119/6309).

Comment: GitHub now automatically generates a table of content for Wikis based on the headings. https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-19-table-of-content-for-wikis/

Answer (score 209, accepted):

It is nicely demonstrated in the Table of Contents of the [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

```
##### Table of Contents  
[Headers](#headers)  
[Emphasis](#emphasis)  
...snip...    
<a name="headers"/>
## Headers
```

If you hover over a Header in a GitHub Markdown file, you'll see a little link sample to the left of it, you can also use that link. The format for that link is `<project URL#<header name>`. The `<header name>` must be all lower case.

Comment: Surely there's a way to autogenerate it like MediaWiki's _ _ TOC _ _?

Comment: @LB--: If you edit a GitHub wiki page and change the "editing style" dropdown to "MediaWiki", you can just use the MediaWiki `__TOC__` directly. Clearly the underlying autogeneration logic is there. But the functionality doesn't seem to be exposed in their Markdown editing style. Quite unfortunate. Let's all start sending in feature requests for it and maybe they'll turn it on.

Comment: I recant on the "underlying autogeneration logic" being there; it looks like the different "editing styles" go through different renderers. Still, it would be great to have this in the MD version since that's pretty popular, and couldn't be hard to add.

Comment: @AndrewJanke I looked into it more, it seems that the MarkDown format doesn't have any support for autogeneration of tables of contents, and they're proud of it.

Comment: There is one catch in creating links. They have to be lower case. I didn't know that and was wondering why my TOC isn't working. I used `#Headers` instead of `#headers`. I thought it was a typo in your answer.  Perhaps you can add to your answer this information.

Comment: If you have section titles with spaces, replace them with hyphens: `[Tailing logs](#tailing-logs)`

Comment: Is there a way to add nesting to TOC ?

Answer (score 76):

#### Visual Studio Code

If you happen to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), there is easy-to-use extension called [Markdown All in One](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) that can make the TOC for any .md file in an instant.

[image]

Just open Command Palette (`Ctrl-Shift-P`) -> `Markdown: Create Table of Contents`

[image: Original md]
[image: After automatic TOC insertion]

#### Auto-update messes your edited TOC?

As an additional tip, you might want to turn the "automatic TOC updates on save" OFF by using

```js
  "markdown.extension.toc.updateOnSave": false,
```

in your Visual Studio Settings (Command Palette -> Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)).

Comment: This was so helpful..from spying your answer to having a TOC on my github repo = ~3 min. Great answer thanks so much, looking forwards to using this plugin in other cases as well.

Answer (score 66):

Since github cannot use `TOC` directly, but we have other alternatives.

You can automatically generate TOC via **Online tool:**

[Generate TOC Table of Contents from GitHub Markdown or Wiki Online](https://ecotrust-canada.github.io/markdown-toc/)

[image]

or via **Local tool:**

[github-markdown-toc](https://github.com/ekalinin/github-markdown-toc)

Comment: The online tool doesn't work with headers like this: "# Chapter 1: Introducing to something". Symbol ``:`` is replaced with hyphen, but it should be removed altogether as per [explanation](https://gist.github.com/rachelhyman/b1f109155c9dafffe618#gistcomment-3310992). Edit: Bug has been reported to Github project.

Answer (score 32):

Update Aug. 2021:

After ToC in README (see March 2021 below), you now have:

> ### [Table of content for Wikis](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-19-table-of-content-for-wikis/)
>
> For Wikis we now automatically generate a table of contents based on the Markdown headings.

As [illustrated here](https://twitter.com/github/status/1428466581554745352):

> Do you wiki?
> We just added an automatic table of contents to the sidebar to help with navigation

[image: Wiki ToC]

---

You can now (March 2021) check out what the CEO of GitHub Nat Friedman [just announced](https://twitter.com/natfriedman/status/1375430850620256257)

> GitHub now automatically creates a table of contents for your http://README.md files from your headers.
>
> After much consideration, we made this a feature of the viewer, not a concern of the editor: no special markdown to insert.

So... it does not modify your markdown (`README.md` or other `.md` files) to insert, or update your text: it only provides a menu which allows quick access to your test sections based on markdown headers.
That may, or may not, what you are after.

[image: toc in markdown README]

Comment: Note that this also works for other .md files, and is not exclusive to README's.

Comment: @Kraigolas Great! That is convenient.

Comment: Note: June 2021: GitLab supports it also: https://twitter.com/tonka_2000/status/1399772594568638465

Comment: @Kraigolas is it possible to make this work also in a gist .md file?

Comment: @abu I didn't see that in gist for now.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't available for the markdown documents in the wikis. So it doesn't answer the question. (that icon doesn't exist in the wiki docs).

Comment: @Michael Strange, I cannot find a trace of this reversal on GitHub blog.

Answer (score 31):

One possible (semi-automated) solution is Eugene Kalinin's `github-markdown-toc`. This tool essentially crunches through  your `README.md` file and snarfs out `#`'s headings to create a TOC.

1. Download the script https://github.com/ekalinin/github-markdown-toc
2. Feed your `README.md` to the script (as noted in Eugene's `README.md`)

   cat README.md | bash github-markdown-toc
3. Cut and paste generated TOC and place it at the top of your `README.md` file

Note that this `bash` implementation only works on Linux (from what I can tell).

As a side note, there is a golang [implementation](https://github.com/ekalinin/github-markdown-toc.go) and is probably more of a hassle to get working.

Answer (score 19):

https://github.com/jonschlinkert/markdown-toc

- `git clone your-repo.wiki.git` (add the `.wiki` right before `.git` to clone the wiki
- `npm i -g markdown-toc`
- Insert `<!-- toc -->` (case sensitive) in your wiki's markdown
- `markdown-toc -i my-wiki-markdown.md` (`-i` will edit it in place)
- Profit

---

**Update:** I think maybe https://github.com/thlorenz/doctoc is more popular now.

Answer (score 16):

Currently it's [not possible](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/904) to do that using markdown syntax (`.md`). There is ongoing unofficial [discussion about automatically generating table of contents TOC](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/215) on rendered markdown files like `README.md` which lists some of the ideas.

However there are some other workarounds such as:

- Use `AsciiDoc` instead as per suggestion from this [comment](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/215#issuecomment-336328746). For example:

  ```
  :toc: macro
  :toc-title:
  :toclevels: 99
  # Title

  toc::[]

  ## A

  ### A2

  ## B

  ### B2
  ```

  Check the example at [`littlebits/react-popover` (`README.adoc`)](https://github.com/littlebits/react-popover).
- Online [Table Of Content Generator](http://tableofcontent.eu/) ([raychenon/play-table-of-contents](https://github.com/raychenon/play-table-of-contents))
- [arthurhammer/github-toc](https://github.com/arthurhammer/github-toc) - browser extension that adds a table of contents to GitHub repos

Comment: Yes, I have been converted to asciidoc largely for the ToC and linking to headers. Got fed up of waiting for Markdown to catch up.

Answer (score 8):

If you are not in the position to stick with ***Markdown***, you can do as below:

> - on *GitHub/wiki*: switch *Markdown* to [***MediaWiki***](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). Use `__TOC__` Syntax. See [sample](https://github.com/MarketLeader/Tutorial-Buka-Toko/wiki).
> - on *GitHub/repo*: switch *Markdown* to [***AsciiDoc***](http://asciidoc.org/). Use `:toc:` Syntax. See [demo](https://github.com/MarketLeader/asciidoc/blob/master/demo.adoc).
> - on *GitHub/repo*: switch *Markdown* to [***reStructuredText***](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents). Use `.. contents::` Syntax.

However, using *Markdown* files in *GitHub/repo*, you can get it on [*GitHub Pages*](https://pages.github.com/) like in [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/)

> - when *Jekyll* is activated, it generates *GitHub Pages* using [***Kramdown***](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/) by default
> - *Kramdown* comes with `Table Of Content`. Use `{:toc}` Syntax. See [*the explanation*](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc).

Answer (score 3):

You can choose the Edit mode "MediaWiki" which will generate a toc for the headers, e.g.

```
== First ==

== Second ==
```

Comment: True. See https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0174.mediawiki for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the fact that github has it's own way of generating id=".." attributes in h1, h2, h3, etc... headers in html version after processing Markdown (for example Bitbucket use little different pattern of sluggifying headers title to id="slug") it is handy to don't reinvent the wheel and use library that reverse engineered this process.

I found one quite good library for this task called [markdown-toc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-toc#cli).

For me it seems the best solution because I always have installed node on my machine.

Just execute **npx markdown-toc -i file.md**.

And it looks like it is one of more popular tools for this task - at least in node.js ecosystem.

```
ls
cat <<EOF >> test.md | tee 
## Table of Contents

<!-- toc -->
- old toc 1
- old toc 2
- old toc 3
<!-- tocstop -->

## abc
This is a b c.

## xyz
This is x y z.
EOF
ls
cat test.md
npx markdown-toc -i test.md
cat test.md
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Pandoc

The swiss army knife of markup:

```
cat README.md | pandoc --from markdown  --toc -s  --to markdown -
```

Answer (score 1):

One more TOC markdown related tool implemented on the top of Perl (which is shipped with Linux/Git-for-Windows always and with Cygwin optionally, and there are no dependencies on extra packages)

https://github.com/ildar-shaimordanov/git-markdown-toc

I guess my tool works similar or almost similar to ekalinin/git-markdown-toc mentioned above by other people. I have never compared tham because his tool is implemented as Go-Lang which doesn't exist on my system. The main goal of my script is to provide the good solution in creating TOC locally -- no any connection to any exteranl hosts and so on, only read a local file (README.md, by default) and create the TOC and embed it to the file.

Comment: dear jsxt  - good day i am urgently in need of having the newest markup manual - which is the best one here the most actual one!?

Comment: @zero, i am not sure that I understand you. If you need a manual, you can find any of them in google. If you need advice on what kind of tools you need, you have to read their descriptions, try and make your decision which one is better in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
[Go to Delete](#delete_lines)

#delete_lines

code here, will be pointed here
```

See: https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

And, to make a nested outline:

```
* 1\. [Go to Delete](#delete_lines)
    * 1.1\. item
    * 1.2\. item
        * 1.2\. item
* 2\. item
```

See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85474/how-to-write-nested-numbered-lists

And for more info and complex linking:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695439/how-to-link-to-a-named-anchor-in-multimarkdown#:~:text=In%20standard%20Markdown%2C%20place%20an,%5Blink%20text%5D(%23abcd)%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695439/how-to-link-to-a-named-anchor-in-multimarkdown#:%7E:text=In%20standard%20Markdown%2C%20place%20an,%5Blink%20text%5D(%23abcd)%20).

Comment: dear folks i am urgently in need of having the newest markup manual - which is the best one here the most actual one!?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mdtoc](https://github.com/Teskann/mdtoc) (I am the author).

Once installed, simply run:

```
mdtoc path/to/file.md
```

Comment: If you can't build and install this, the next best thing is: `cat README.md | pandoc --from markdown  --toc -s  --to markdown -`