# Gist Vs. Repository for Tutorial

Tags: github, gist

I'm publishing a tutorial that includes a lot of code interspersed with documentation. I'm considering two ways of hosting the code:

1. Separate git repository with code files and markdown files explaining the code
2. Github gist containing both of these

Are there advantages of hosting in a gist v/s a repository? When would one prefer one of these over the other?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Gist is a simple way to share snippets and pastes with others.
Whereas Repo is simply a place where the history of your work is stored.

There is no good answer, it's personal preference. I make mine a conceptual distinction. If it's code designed to demonstrate a technique, teach a principle, or show off a solution it goes in a gist. Doesn't matter if it's one file or 30 files. If it's actual code intended to be run, used as is, or forked as boilerplate I put it in a proper repository.

Comment: "Doesn't matter if it's one file or 30 files"... but it does matter if you need subdirectories. Gist does not support directories.

Answer (score 3):

If you use markdown files for your tutorial, now there is one important difference, even if you are only creating one file (and specially if it is a long one).

[Since April 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-13-table-of-contents-support-in-markdown-files/), .md files created in github repositories now include an automatic Table of Contents which greatly improves navegability. See this related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824119/710788) for more info.

As far as I know, this automatic ToC does not exist in gist-created .md files, so I'd rather go for a repository in this case (OP mentioned "a lot of code interspersed with documentation").