# How can I create a table of content in GitLab wiki?

Tags: gitlab, wiki, gitlab-wiki

I am a big fan of the `__TOC__` that creates a table of content on a Wikimedia page.

Whenever you write things like this on a Wikimedia page:

```
This is a page for my project

## Credits ##

bla bla

## License ##

bla bla
```

`__TOC_` automagically creates a table of content that allows you to navigate through inner links of the page.

I noticed that this is somehow possible in GitHub wiki pages: [How do I create some kind of table of content in GitHub wiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18244417/1983854) by using different tricks.

However, I miss this feature in GitLab wiki pages. Does it provide such functionality?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

So this exists! I finally found a Merge Request in in the GitLab Community Edition: [Replace Gollum [[_TOC_]] tag with result of TableOfContentsFilter](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/2952)

As its name describes, to have a table of contents you need to write the following:

```
[[_TOC_]]
```

All together, you can write something like:

```
This is a page for my project

[[_TOC_]]

## Credits

bla bla

## License

bla bla
```

and will show like this:

> [image]

This is available from the [GitLab 8.6 release](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/22/gitlab-8-6-released/) as described in [its milestone](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/milestones/22).

Comment: This no longer appears to work. has it been replaced?

Comment: @Jwely what version of GitLab are you using? It works well in my 11.3. You can also try what is described in the [Markdown Guide by GitLB](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/engineering/technical-writing/markdown-guide/#table-of-contents-toc)

Comment: The error was mine. I presumed this would render online for a top level project README.md, when it is only intended to work when using the wiki features of gitlab.

Comment: @Jwely ah right, it makes sense. There are some requests to have this in place: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/21901

Answer (score 2):

This should be easier with [GitLab 15.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#visualize-table-of-contents-in-the-wysiwyg-wiki-editor) (August 2022):

> ### Visualize table of contents in the WYSIWYG wiki editor
>
> When you’re editing a wiki page in the rich text WYSIWYG editor, you expect to see an accurate representation of the content as it will appear after it’s published.
> Some elements are too complex for plain text formatting, and require short codes or macros that generate content when the page is built.
>
> A wiki’s table of contents is one example: it generates a list from your page’s subheadings, simplifying navigation of very long pages.
> However, WYSIWYG page editing displayed a table of contents as a static placeholder block.
>
> **GitLab 15.3 shows a visual representation of the Table of Contents in the WYSIWYG wiki editor**.
>
> To add a table of contents while editing a page, select the plus (+) icon in the toolbar, then select **`Table of Contents`**.
> The table of contents updates in real time as you create and edit subheadings on the page, helping you monitor the outline of your longer wiki pages.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/#content-editor) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/366525).

Answer (score 0):

*Should be something like this*

```
 ##### Table of Contents  
[1.-First Topic](#first-topic)
[2.-Second Topic](#second-topic) 
[3.-Third Topic](#third_topic)
```

*And then you will reference each on the same page by using*

```
 <a name="first-topic"/>
 <a name="second-topic"/>
 <a name="third-topic"/>
```

Comment: Note, though, that `[[_TOC_]]` creates this content automatically, which is what I was asking for in the question. We always have time to make it manually, but automagically is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{{< toc >}}` on top of the document. It should automatically generate the TOC for you.

Comment: where did you try it? In my GitLab 11.3.3-ee it does not work, while [`[[_TOC_]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47154662/1983854) does

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `[TOC]` or aforementioned `[[_TOC_]]` as described on [the link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#table-of-contents).