# How to create a side menu by using jekyll with markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have a ready markdown file wanna to display on html. Understand that jekyll has done the job, but I wanna to have a floating side menu, but I can't find any document from jekyll. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Leap day theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/leap-day) will generate a floating menu for `table of contents` of current page.

- You can [preview the theme to see what it looks like](https://pages-themes.github.io/leap-day/)

It is one of the github pages [Supported themes](https://pages.github.com/themes/)

Answer (score -2):

If you want a table of contents in Markdown, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948245/markdown-to-create-pages-and-table-of-contents). If you want to create a menu, you can an include whith this content:

```
<ul>
  <li {% if page.url contains '/getting-started' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/getting-started/">Getting started</a></li>
  <li {% if page.url contains '/without-plugin' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/without-plugins/">Without plugins</a></li>
  <li {% if page.url contains '/about' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
  <li {% if page.url contains '/blog' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Use the include in your layout file, like this:

```
{% include simple-menu.html %}
```

Source: https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/simple-menu

Note that creating a floating menu in plain Markdown is not possible. That is why you have not received any 'real' answers. However, Markdown does support HTML and Github Pages has automatic [TOC's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9898502). But adding HTML to your Markdown file is an ugly hack and you might not be using Github Pages/redcarpet.