# jQuery Waypoints from Greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, jquery-waypoints

I'm attempting to use the jQuery Waypoints plugin from a Greasemonkey script, and can't seem to get even basic tests to work. Does anyone know of a reason Waypoints wouldn't work from a user script?

@require lines:

```
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @require     http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.waypoints/2.0.2/waypoints.min.js
```

Script:

```
$('div.container').waypoint(function(){
    alert('you hit bottom');
},{ offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
```

Interestingly, if this div with the "container" class exists, the script breaks, and code outside this statement will not run. If I change the selector to find some non-existent element, the rest of the script runs fine.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I'm banging my head against the wall. Thanks!

PS. I've also tried pasting the Waypoints plugin code directly into the script (instead of using the CDN), and I get the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that extension is not as well written as many other jQuery extensions.  It uses `this`, and `jQuery` in, let's say, "unfortunate" ways.  This means that it crashes from a userscript scope, even if `@grant none` is set.

For libraries, like this, your options are:

- **Find a better library (recommended).**
- Find a better way to code this yourself, if it's not too involved.
- If the page doesn't use jQuery, or uses a compatible version of jQuery, then you can use such extensions via *Script Injection*.  See below.
- If the page uses an incompatible version of jQuery, there may be nothing you can do without breaking the page.  *Sometimes* a workaround is possible, but that is for another question.

---

## Case where the page already uses a compatible version of jQuery:

You just need to inject Waypoints and any code that uses Waypoints. Do not use `@require`.
Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

function GM_main () {
    $('div.container').waypoint(function(){
        alert('you hit bottom');
    },{ offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
}

addJS_Node (
    null,
    "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.waypoints/2.0.2/waypoints.min.js",
    null,
    function () {addJS_Node (null, null, GM_main); }
);

//-- This is a standard-ish utility function.
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

---

## Case where the page doesn't use jQuery at all:

You need to inject jQuery and then chain the injection of Waypoints and any code that uses Waypoints. Do not use `@require`.
Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

function GM_main () {
    $('div.container').waypoint(function(){
        alert('you hit bottom');
    },{ offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
}

//-- Add jQuery.
addJS_Node (
    null,
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js",
    null,
    addWaypointsAndFireMain
);

function addWaypointsAndFireMain () {
    addJS_Node (
        null,
        "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.waypoints/2.0.2/waypoints.min.js",
        null,
        function () {addJS_Node (null, null, GM_main); }
    );
}

//-- This is a standard-ish utility function.
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

---

---

Unfortunately, when you have to inject your script's code, it becomes much messier to use `GM_` functions.  If this applies to you, see: ["How to call Greasemonkey's GM_ functions from code that must run in the target page scope?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14229539/331508)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation! Unfortunately I do need to provide a jQuery library and use GM_ functions in this case, so I'll probably just code something myself rather than try to mangle Waypoints in (so I haven't tested these code snippets, even though they are much appreciated), but at least now I know I'm not crazy. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem, I tested these *full, working scripts* before I posted them (Changing only the `@include`).   Sorry Waypoints isn't working out for you.  Good Luck with your script!

Comment: Update: It seems the `.scroll` event is altogether unavailable in the user script scope. I determined that after all libraries and custom code I tried failed -- which prompted me to simply test the jQuery `.scroll` event, and that also failed. What finally worked was the `unsafeWindow.onscroll` event. Example:`unsafeWindow.onscroll = function(){alert('you scrolled')};` My guess is that Greasemonkey's security wrapper causes scripts to think nothing has actually moved.

Comment: Pretty sure scroll works (or did).  I'll put this on the list to investigate.  You might even make a question for that, if you want.

Comment: I just posted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119664/scroll-event-in-greasemonkey-scripts

Comment: I deleted the question. Looks like I was using .scroll the wrong way -- I thought I could attach it to elements to see if they moved as a result of scrolling, but it actually only applies to window or scrolling text field elements. Still, absolutely no libraries for attaching an event to an element's moving into view are working, but having access to a .scroll event should let me custom code this. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, I was going to answer.  Anyway, I just verified that `document.addEventListener ("scroll", doSomethingOnScroll, false);` works from a GM script.  Good luck!

Comment: A pull request to make Waypoints' usage of `this` and `jQuery` more fortunate would be welcome.

Comment: @imakewebthings; I would've but I'd already spent too much time on this question and couldn't see an easy way to refactor that code.  Also, I don't use Waypoints and I detest pages that hijack scrolling, so the motivation wasn't there.