# Where does GM_setValue store data?

Tags: google-chrome, tampermonkey

Where does GM_setValue store the data to in chrome. I've tried to determine where the data is going but couldn't figure it out. I monitored with process monitor and saw that when I stored a value chrome was updating a chrome_iwoeoiifoi2h3iofhufsdfnvdf type of file and I opened that up with an sqlite browser but the data was not there. I've looked at all the recently modified files trying to find the data but could not find it.

Latest chrome/TM.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Tampermonkey, `GM_setValue()` data is stored in a [LevelDB database](https://github.com/google/leveldb) that can be found in [the *User Data Directory*](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) tree.

Once in Chrome's "User Data Directory" (EG: `C:\Users\USER_JOE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\`),

**navigate to the  `Local Extension Settings\dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo` folder**.

(`gcalenpjmijncebpfijmoaglllgpjagf` for the Tampermonkey Beta.)

There you will find a [LevelDB database](https://github.com/google/leveldb), usually named `CURRENT`.  You can manipulate it with tools like [LevelDB JSON](https://github.com/nisaacson/leveldb-json), but external support for  LevelDB currently appears to be spotty and I did not find any working tools for Windows yet (might have to compile your own).

You can also [use the Chrome *Storage Area Explorer* extension to explore the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42775918/331508).

As of Tampermonkey 4.3.6, you can **see an individual script's data with the *Storage* tab** in the built-in script editor: (if the 'Storage' tab is not visible, edit Tampermonkey Settings > General Config mode > Advanced)

[image: Script Storage editor]

---

---

---

### OLD, Pre November-ish 2015:

- Before, about November 2015, data was stored in a [Web SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-sql/info) in  `databases\chrome-extension_dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo_0`.

Once you have navigated to the correct folder, you will typically see two files.  On my machine, they are currently just named `4` and `6`.  These are both [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info) files (the backend for Chrome's Web SQL implementation) and can be inspected with a SQLite viewer/utility.

The (normally) larger file, `6` on my machine, is a somewhat disturbing list of 94-thousand userscripts!  I'm not sure what purpose it serves, but haven't investigated it much.

The smaller file (initially, at least), `4` on my machine, is where all the information about/for your userscripts is kept.  This includes any data set by `GM_setValue()`.

---

For example, if I install and run this userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _GM_setValue demo
// @match    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant    GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

GM_setValue ('foo', 'bar');
```

And then I inspect the `config` table in file `4`, I will see four entries like this:
  
[![DB entries for sample script][8]][8]

The one you want is the `@st` row.  Notice how it has the `GM_setValue` data encoded? :

[image: DB entry, money shot]

Comment: Can anyone confirm this still works with TM3.11, Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m?

Comment: Thanks for sanity check Brock. I am working on it and will post results, feared GM_set/getValue may have stopped working, but glad to report they still do work as expected, haven't found where the data is being stored as yet!

Comment: @RichardPlester @BrockAdams Tampermonkey settings are now stored as a levelDB in `\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo`. Tools like [leveldb-json](https://github.com/nisaacson/leveldb-json) can be used to edit this.

Comment: I can find the file named `current` in the said folder, but this file has only 16 bytes and hasn't been changed for years. It likely only contains some references. The actual data seems to be in a file named `000043.log` in the same folder on my computer.

Comment: On Mac I fouund it in : ` "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome//Default/Local Extension Settings/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/`