# Access GM_getValue outside of script

Tags: tampermonkey

Basically the question title. It would greatly benefit me. I want to be able to access `GM_getValue` outside of my userscript for debugging purposes, or, at the very least, the values and names themselves.

I am in Chrome on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Latest Tampermonkey beta (and eventually normal Tampermonkey) displays the GM values in its **dashboard script editor in `Storage` tab**.
- **Visual method: use [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) extension:**

  1. Open the Tampermonkey dashboard page and invoke devtools by <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
  2. In Storage Area Explorer panel scroll to the bottom to find the `@uid#` of your script by name, then find its data in `@st#` key with that UID:

     [image: SAE]

---

- **Dumping in the console:**

  One-time setup: add a new code `snippet` in devtools - Sources - Snippets subpanel and save it:

  ```js
  function dumpGM_data(scriptName) {
      chrome.storage.local.get(null, data => {
          const UID = Object.keys(data).find(k => k.startsWith('@uid#') &&
                                                  data[k].value == scriptName);
          if (UID)
              console.log(data[UID.replace('@uid', '@st')].value.data);
      });
  }
  ```

  1. Open the Tampermonkey dashboard page and invoke devtools by <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
  2. open and run that snippet: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> - it'll be usable until you close the dashboard page
  3. invoke it in the console:

     ```js
     dumpGM_data('SE Preview on hover')
     ```

---

- **Inspect/dump/edit the database file directly:**

  Use any LevelDB tool you can find (or compile one yourself) on the `ldb` database file under [Chrome user profile directory](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) in `Local Extension Settings/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo` or `Local Extension Settings/gcalenpjmijncebpfijmoaglllgpjagf` for Tampermonkey beta.