# GM_xmlhttpRequest doesn't work during onbeforeunload in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, userscripts, onbeforeunload

In my script, `GM_xmlhttpRequest` doesn't work, but regular `xmlhttpRequest` does. (But I need `GM_xmlhttpRequest` because the call is cross-domain.)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (){
    try{
        details = GM_xmlhttpRequest({
           method: "GET",
           url: "http://www.example.com",
           synchronous: true // this been tried with both possible values
        });
        console.log(details); // Object {abort: function}
    }
    catch(e){ // catch is not being triggered
        console.log(e);   
    }
    return "dontleave";
}
```

The same code does exactly what it is expected to in Firefox (AJAX first, then continue).

Regular `xmlhttpRequest` also does what it should in that spot (but it doesn't allow cross domain calls).

What is wrong?

Comment: Chrome is much stricter about cross-scope functions between a userscript and page.  Try the technique from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14255440/331508) as a start, but you may also have to block the page unload since messaging is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the problem was caused because Tampermonkey, the addon that handles userscripts in Chrome, does not supports `GM_xmlhttpRequest` fully - it doesn't allows synchronous calls. To make things worse, Chrome itself blocks execution of any asynchronous callbacks during `unbeforeunload` (delays them until `ununload`).

We found absolutely no acceptable way around this and had to abandon the script and leave users with limited-functional replacement for Chrome.