# Binding to an event of the unsafeWindow in Firefox 30 with Greasemonkey 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm maintaining a Greasemonkey script and got some trouble due to [Mozilla's change to the unsafeWindow API](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/) in Firefox 30.

The page my script runs on, triggers an event "MyEvent" and my script is interested in that event.

The event is fired using jQuery 1.6.4

Before, I used this code to hook into this event:

```
var jQuery = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
jQuery(unsafeWindow.document)
    .bind("MyEvent", function() {
        console.log("MyEvent Triggered!");
    });
```

But due to Mozilla's change this won’t work anymore.

I tried to insert my own jQuery in conflict-free mode but I don't think this can access events that are triggered by the other jQuery instance?

Any ideas how I could hook into this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do this, **if you don't need any `GM_` functions** and you **don't `@require` your own jQuery**, is to use `@grant none` mode.  This works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _unsafeWindow tests
// @include  http://jsbin.com/xaman/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var jQuery = window.jQuery;
jQuery(document).bind ("MyEvent", function () {
    console.log ("From GM script: MyEvent caught!");
} );
```

---

If you did need `GM_` functions, you can sometimes use [the new `exportFunction()`](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/#user-content-exportfunction).
Unfortunately, jQuery and jQuery event handling is a special case.  Depending on what you try, you will get error messages like:

> Permission denied to access property 'handler'
>   or
>   CloneNonReflectorsWrite error

I've simply found no way to do this using any of the new `unsafeWindow` functionality.  Your only recourse is to inject the code. Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _unsafeWindow tests
// @include  http://jsbin.com/xaman/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
function myEventHandler (zEvent) {
    console.log (
        'From GM script: "' + zEvent.type + '" triggered on ', zEvent.target
    );
}

function bindMyEvent () {
    //-- Gets "jQuery is not defined" if GM script does not also use jQuery.
    jQuery(document).bind ("MyEvent", myEventHandler);
    console.log ("The jQuery version being used is: ", jQuery.fn.jquery);
}

//-- Create A COPY OF myEventHandler in the target page scope:
addJS_Node (myEventHandler);
//-- Create A COPY OF bindMyEvent in the target page scope and immediately run it.
addJS_Node (null, null, bindMyEvent);

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

---

## You can test both of these scripts against [this jsBin page](http://jsbin.com/xaman/1).

---

If you need to run/call `GM_` functions from within the injected event handler(s), use techniques shown in "[How to call Greasemonkey's GM_ functions from code that must run in the target page scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229539/how-to-call-greasemonkeys-gm-functions-from-code-that-must-run-in-the-target-p) ".

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is really talking about GreaseMonkey - the blog post linked is about content scripts in the Add-on SDK.

Comment: @WladimirPalant, that's because Greasemonkey 2.0 copied the SDK changes and referenced that SDK blog post for the workarounds. See [the Greasemonkey 2.0 announcement](http://www.greasespot.net/2014/06/greasemonkey-20-release.html).  Most GM users can temporarily fix these unsafeWindow problems by reverting to previous GM versions -- at least for FF 30.

Comment: The OP is rally talking about GreaseMonkey! @BrockAdams AWESOME! The second snipped is kind of a monster but so is this script I have to maintain here. Works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just don't bind event handlers on `unsafeWindow`, use the regular `window` object instead:

```
window.document.addEventListener("MyEvent", function() {
  console.log("MyEvent Triggered!");
}, false, true);
```

Note the fourth parameter (`wantsUntrusted`) to [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) - this one allows your event handler to receive untrusted events.

Comment: This does not work on custom events triggered by jQuery. Test it against [jsbin.com/xaman/1](http://jsbin.com/xaman/1).  Also, the `wantsUntrusted` parameter is not needed for/with Greasemonkey scripts.

Comment: @BrockAdams: You are right, jQuery implements an "alternative" event dispatching mechanism - I forgot about that huge WTF. One needs to dispatch events properly of course.

Comment: Yes, but the OP can't control how the target page, or jQuery, dispatches the events.

Comment: A soloution short like this would have been awesome! But as Brock already said, I have no control over how the page dispachtes the events.