# How do I replace unsafeWindow when migrating a pre-Firefox 30 Greasemonkey script to GM4+?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4

I'm trying to get a reference to the version of jQuery that exists on my webpage in a Greasemonkey script that worked until Firefox 30. In comments below my definition are the two other references I could find, but I just get `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` or `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` when I try to access jQuery on the window object.

```
var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
//var jQuery = window.jQuery; // From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802606/binding-to-an-event-of-the-unsafewindow-in-firefox-30-with-greasemonkey-2-0
//var jQuery = $ || window.wrappedJSObject.$; // https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2700#issuecomment-345538182
function addAccountNameToTitle(jNode) {
  $('title').text(session.name + " | " + $('title').text());
}

waitForKeyElements (".page-breadcrumb", addAccountNameToTitle, false);

/*--- waitForKeyElements():  A handy, utility function that
    does what it says.
*/
function waitForKeyElements (
    selectorTxt,    /* Required: The jQuery selector string that
                        specifies the desired element(s).
                    */
    actionFunction, /* Required: The code to run when elements are
                        found. It is passed a jNode to the matched
                        element.
                    */
    bWaitOnce,      /* Optional: If false, will continue to scan for
                        new elements even after the first match is
                        found.
                    */
    iframeSelector  /* Optional: If set, identifies the iframe to
                        search.
                    */
)
{
    var targetNodes, btargetsFound;

    if (typeof iframeSelector == "undefined")
        targetNodes     = $(selectorTxt);
    else
        targetNodes     = $(iframeSelector).contents ()
                                           .find (selectorTxt);

    if (targetNodes  &&  targetNodes.length > 0) {
        /*--- Found target node(s).  Go through each and act if they
            are new.
        */
        targetNodes.each ( function () {
            var jThis        = $(this);
            var alreadyFound = jThis.data ('alreadyFound')  ||  false;

            if (!alreadyFound) {
                //--- Call the payload function.
                actionFunction (jThis);
                jThis.data ('alreadyFound', true);
            }
        } );
        btargetsFound   = true;
    }
    else {
        btargetsFound   = false;
    }

    //--- Get the timer-control variable for this selector.
    var controlObj      = waitForKeyElements.controlObj  ||  {};
    var controlKey      = selectorTxt.replace (/[^\w]/g, "_");
    var timeControl     = controlObj [controlKey];

    //--- Now set or clear the timer as appropriate.
    if (btargetsFound  &&  bWaitOnce  &&  timeControl) {
        //--- The only condition where we need to clear the timer.
        clearInterval (timeControl);
        delete controlObj [controlKey]
    }
    else {
        //--- Set a timer, if needed.
        if ( ! timeControl) {
            timeControl = setInterval ( function () {
                    waitForKeyElements (    selectorTxt,
                                            actionFunction,
                                            bWaitOnce,
                                            iframeSelector
                                        );
                },
                500
            );
            controlObj [controlKey] = timeControl;
        }
    }
    waitForKeyElements.controlObj   = controlObj;
}
```

I'm using FF 59.0.2 and Greasemonkey 4.3

Comment: I'm going to try getting this to work today, but hopefully there's an easy answer.

Comment: The easy answer is that's the exact wrong approach.  `@require` the jQuery WFKE and use a grant other than `none`.  Provide your FF and GM versions.  And per GM's developers, don't use GM4+. Use Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is just the script that I've had working for the past 3 years or so. Now I'm trying to update myself on everything I missed. I'm using FF 59.0.2 and GreaseMonkey 4.3. Isn't the reason people use Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey because they insert a `<script>` tag with the jQuery version? Ideally, I'd like to use the same jQuery version as my website.

Comment: People use Tampermonkey on FF because GM4 broke everybody's scripts and has a great many bugs, while losing many features.  Tampermonkey was already better in terms of functionality and performance anyway.  And [GM's developers say to switch](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsafeWindow.jQuery` was never a good idea and rarely worked. Also, see [Error: Permission denied to access property 'handler'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719256/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-handler).

The *smart* thing to do with the question code is to use `@require`, like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Changing the title text on some page.
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements (".page-breadcrumb", addAccountNameToTitle);

function addAccountNameToTitle (jNode) {
    $('title').text (session.name + " | " + $('title').text() );
}
```

Advantages:

- Short, simple, and clear.
- Not vulnerable to side effects from changing javascripts on target page.  Especially, if the target page changes jQuery versions.
- Uses speedy, local versions of jQuery and waitForKeyElements.  They are stored on the local disk and often cached in memory.  No server fetches nor delays.

Note:  if `session` is a target page global variable, you may need to access it like `unsafeWindow.session.name`.  See: [How to access `window` (Target page) objects when @grant values are set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778469/how-to-access-window-target-page-objects-when-grant-values-are-set).

---

---

---

You state that you want to use the page's jQuery instance or version.  There is seldom a good reason to do that.  And the code, shown in this question, certainly wouldn't benefit from that.

But, **if your userscript doesn't use any GM functions**, you can do that via `@grant none` mode like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Changing the title text on some page.
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements (".page-breadcrumb", addAccountNameToTitle);

function addAccountNameToTitle (jNode) {
    $('title').text (session.name + " | " + $('title').text() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was able to fix two of my Greasemonkey scripts and while I was at it I brought my Stylish user styles up to date with the new format. I have one Greasemonkey script that's entering an infinite loop when it reaches line 53 of waitForKeyElements that I'm debugging now.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help. Line 53 is only called once per node, unless your callback returns a non zero/false/null value.  Open a new question if you need to.

Comment: Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333445/how-do-i-fix-an-infinite-waitforkeyelements-loop-in-greasemonkey