# JIRA.bind() is not working in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jira, greasemonkey

As the title says, I am unable to get the JIRA.bind() call working from my Greasemonkey script and I am running out of ideas why and what to try else.

I am running JIRA 6.4.14 and Greasemonkey 3.9 in Firefox 50.1.0.

If I open JIRA and execute this line in the Firefox built-in console, it works and "GO" is displayed after committing an inline change:

```
JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE, function(e, context, reason){alert("GO");})
```

So, I thought it should be no problem to port this command into Greasemonkey:

```
unsafeWindow.JIRA.bind(unsafeWindow.JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE, function(e, context, reason){alert("GO");})
```

But nothing happens, when I do the exact same inline edit.
The line itself is executed, I "alerted" before and after and both popups came up.

I tried some other variations of the call, all without success

```
unsafeWindow.JIRA.bind(unsafeWindow.JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE, function(e, context, reason){ unsafeWindow.alert("GO");})
unsafeWindow.AJS.$(unsafeWindow.JIRA.bind(unsafeWindow.JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE, function(e, context, reason){alert("GO");}))
unsafeWindow.JIRA.bind(unsafeWindow.JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE, function(){ alert("GO");})
// While 'fooBar' is a simple function doing the alert("go")
unsafeWindow.JIRA.bind(unsafeWindow.JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE, function(){ fooBar })
```

Does anyone know how to make the bind work?

---

Trying the exportFunction did not solved the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    unsafeWindow.JIRA.bind(unsafeWindow.JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE, function(e, context, reason){ foobar });

});

function foobar()
{
    alert("GO");
}

exportFunction(foobar, unsafeWindow);
```

---

### SOLUTION:

Thank you Brock Adams and wOxxOm for your help!

This snipped is working just fine and printing both messages "Binding" and "Go".

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Write a log message from inside of the GM script
    anotherMethod("Binding");

    // Bind the exported foobar to the JIRA event
    unsafeWindow.JIRA.bind(
        unsafeWindow.JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE,
        unsafeWindow.foobar
    );

});

// Implementation of the foobar function
function foobar(e, context, reason)
{
    anotherMethod("Go");
}

// Another method, that will get called from the GM script and the exported foobar
function anotherMethod(msg)
{
    console.log(msg);
}

// Export foobar to the unsafeWindow to make it accessible for JIRA
unsafeWindow.foobar = exportFunction(foobar, unsafeWindow);
```

Comment: You need `exportFunction(function(){ blabla }, unsafeWindow)` to export the function into the unsafe context.

Comment: I tried the exportFunction without success.

Comment: Well, exportFunction is a wrapper that creates a function so you should pass it to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [How to access `window` (Target page) objects when @grant values are set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778469/how-to-access-window-target-page-objects-when-grant-values-are-set).

Everything in the `.bind()` call must reside in the target page scope, so you can't use dynamic `function () {...}` code like that.

Bind your callback like so:

```js
function mySaveComplete (e, context, reason) {
    //alert ("GO");
    console.log ("Go");
}
unsafeWindow.mySaveComplete = exportFunction (mySaveComplete, unsafeWindow);

unsafeWindow.JIRA.bind (
    unsafeWindow.JIRA.Events.INLINE_EDIT_SAVE_COMPLETE,
    unsafeWindow.mySaveComplete
);
```

*However*, I don't have access to a JIRA test bed.  In certain situations, you may have to inject the code, as the linked answer states.
In that case, see also: [How to call Greasemonkey's GM_ functions from code that must run in the target page scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229539/how-to-call-greasemonkeys-gm-functions-from-code-that-must-run-in-the-target-p)