# Firefox addon + YouTube API: how to get video current time by clicking on toolbar button?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, youtube-api, toolbar

In my Firefox addon, I have a custom button on nav toolbar. In my *.xul file, I have the following:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
  <toolbarbutton id="myaddon-button-1"/>
  </toolbarpalette>

<!-- button details -->
<toolbarbutton id="myaddon-button-1"
  label="MyAddon"
  tooltiptext="My Addon Desc"
  oncommand="myaddon[1]()"
  class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional myaddon"
  />
```

In my *.js script, I have the following:

```
myaddon = {

1: function () {

    ytplayer = gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById("movie_player");

    alert ("before");

    alert (ytplayer.getCurrentTime());

    alert ("after");

},
```

After clicking on a custom toolbar button, I get alert "before" and don't get alert "after". In Error Console, I have

```
Error: ytplayer.getCurrentTime is not a function
```

In the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220250/how-to-call-this-youtube-function-from-greasemonkey) related to GreaseMonkey, I have read about embedding a piece of html and calling YouTube API inside. And it works, I tested it in Firefox. But I don't want to inject any html elements and click on them. Could you please give me any clue on how to call YouTube API functions like getCurrentTime in toolbar button handler?

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sandbox = Components.utils.Sandbox(gBrowser.contentWindow,{sandboxPrototype:gBrowser.contentWindow, wantXrays:false});
var currenttime = Components.utils.evalInSandbox("document.getElementById('movie_player').getCurrentTime()", sandbox);
```