# Adding @grant to a GM script breaks the overload of XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, prototype, greasemonkey, overloading

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script where I want to overload the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` function to hijack the Ajax calls on the page.

I'm using the following code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        name
// @namespace   namespace
// @description desc
// @include     https://url*
// @version     1.0
// ==/UserScript==

if (XMLHttpRequest.prototype) {
    //New Firefox Versions
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    var myOpen = function(method, url, async, user, password) {

        //call original
        this.realOpen (method, url, async, user, password);
        myCode();

    }  
    //ensure all XMLHttpRequests use our custom open method
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = myOpen ;
}
```

This works well until I start using GM APIs. When I just add the following line to the meta section my code breaks, and `myOpen` is no longer called:

```
// @grant       GM_getValue
```

This could be any GM API really, and my code breaks.
Everything else in my script works fine even with the GM APIs, it's just the overload of the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` function that breaks.

I can kind of workaround it by using `waitForKeyElements`, however, I don't like it because it slows down the browser due to the interval it uses.

Any ideas why the GM APIs break the overload of the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` call?

Many thanks,

Peter

Comment: If you have a case where `waitForKeyElements` really slows down the page, I'd like to see it.  (I coded the original waitForKeyElements and want to eliminate bugs and performance issues as much as is, cost-effectively, possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `@grant` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant) switches Greasemonkey's sandbox back on -- which it must have to use any of the `GM_` functions.

That `prototype` override would then only affect the script scope, and you want it to affect the page scope.  To get around this, you need to *inject* the override.  Like so:

```
function overrideXhrFunctions () {
    if (XMLHttpRequest.prototype) {
        //New Firefox Versions
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
        var myOpen = function(method, url, async, user, password) {

            //call original
            this.realOpen (method, url, async, user, password);
            myCode();
        }
        //ensure all XMLHttpRequests use our custom open method
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = myOpen ;
    }
}

addJS_Node (null, null, overrideXhrFunctions) {

//-- addJS_Node is a standard(ish) function
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';
    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

---

---

Note that mixing `GM_` functions and injected code can get tricky.  See ["How to use GM_xmlhttpRequest in Injected Code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11377191/331508) for one way to do that.