# How to compile a Google Chrome extension out of code I found at userscripts.org?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I came across [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/120682) which works in Google Chrome.

I want to use it as Google Chrome extension as this will give me experience to convert many other codes from userscripts to Google Chrome Extensions.

Can someone give me a step by step tutorial of how to make a Google Chrome Extension out of [this userscript code](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/120682)?

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Facebook Ads Hider
// @author         Jose Luis Martin
// @namespace      http://joseluismartin.info
// @description    Hide Ads on Facebook
// @include        http://www.facebook.com/*
// @run-at         document-start
// 
// ==/UserScript==

if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", onNodeInserted, false);
}

// Event listener to hide ads containers
function onNodeInserted(event) {
    target = event.target;
    if (target.className == "ego_column") {
        hideElement(target);
    }
}

// trivial hide of ads container
function hideElement(elto) {
    elto.style.visibility = "hidden";
    elto.style.hight = "0px";
    elto.style.width = "0px";
}
```

Please do not give a reply that there is no need for this as userscripts can be natively run on Google Chrome. I am doing this to learn how to make Google Chrome extensions.

[The Google Chrome extension tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) is very bad for understanding and makes me vomit - I don't know who made it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Google Chrome, userscripts **are** extensions.  The script gets packaged as a [*content script*](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), and the extension `manifest.json` gets automatically generated.

To move towards a "full fledged" extension:

1. First organize your script, source file(s) and explicitly create the `manifest.json` as shown in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259212/331508).
2. You do not need to alter that userscript's code, at this point, but you will want to transfer the values of the `@include` and `@run-at` directives to the `manifest.json` file you will generate.  Refer to the example in that linked answer.
3. Read [the *Content Scripts* page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and note how the manifest can be used to easily add CSS, jQuery, your userscript (AKA content script), etc.
4. *Content scripts* are 1 of the 3 main tools available to Chrome extensions.  The other 2 are the *background page* and *UI pages*.  Learn more about those starting with [the extension-development *Overview*](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html).
5. Finally, you can package your extension as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11481476/331508).

Comment: So you can't modify the user.js file without using extensions.  Well this means no headless chrome adding user.js RIP.  Firefox allows this.