# Where are Chrome/Tampermonkey userscripts stored on the filesystem?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

Where are Chrome/Tampermonkey userscripts stored on the filesystem?

I want to edit user scripts directly instead of using the hokey in-browser editor.

Comment: On Windows 7 they are installed here `C:\Users\cbrand\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` which is to say my user folder, the `AppData\Local` being the version of .files on Windows, which doesn't have any sort of "use .name to hide the file by default", and then etc. Maybe it's similarly nested on OSX? After that, there's a folder for each userscript, and a database of the active extensions.

Comment: I disagree with the close on this, its absolutely related to programming. Knowing where to find the userscripts can be key to editing/programming them.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the OS-specific aspect since Brock's answer works across OSs.

Comment: As said in this answer [https://superuser.com/a/1149989/398785] you can find them in :

```%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo\```

Comment: See also [_How to update a userscript's code in Tampermonkey's extension storage directly_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76451614/1744774).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Tampermonkey scripts are super easy to update via the Tampermonkey tab. See [the Tampermonkey FAQ](http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=78), or just try it.

Tampermonkey scripts were stored in a special SQLite database and were/are not directly editable in file form.
**Update:** As of [version 3.5.3630](http://tampermonkey.net/changelog.php?ext=dhdg&more=true#v3.5.3630), Tampermonkey scripts are now stored using Chrome's extension storage. They are still not editable in file form, but the developer of Tampermonkey (derjanb) has helpfully made [a Python script to extract them.](https://gist.github.com/derjanb/9f6c10168e63c3dc3cf0)

---

Chrome ***Userscripts*** (not the same as Tampermonkey scripts) are stored as follows, for the Chrome and Chromium browsers:

```
Windows XP:
  Chrome  : %AppData%\..\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\
  Chromium: %AppData%\..\Local Settings\Application Data\Chromium\User Data\Default\Extensions\  

Windows Vista/7/8:
  Chrome  : %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\
  Chromium: %LocalAppData%\Chromium\User Data\Default\Extensions\

Linux:
  Chrome  : ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/
  Chromium: ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/

Mac OS X:
  Chrome  : ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/
  Chromium: ~/Library/Application Support/Chromium/Default/Extensions/
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259212/331508) or [this Google Groups thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6EVtjeaWObs/discussion%5B1-25%5D).
Note that Chrome userscripts are automatically made into Chrome extensions with an auto-generated manifest.

**However:**

1. Editing these files in place will not work. Chrome ignores and/or overwrites the changes.
2. For Userscripts, set up your environment as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259212/331508), for easy editing and updating.
3. **Tampermonkey scripts** are not stored the same way.  <strike>They are stored, by Tampermonkey in a special SQLite database and are not directly editable that way.</strike>  UPDATE: This was changed with [version 3.5.3630](http://tampermonkey.net/changelog.php?ext=dhdg&more=true#v3.5.3630), or so.  See above.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to easily share them externally, so that others could download (via a link or cp script)
It seems that's not possible.

Comment: It is possible to export using the utilities tab on the dashboard

Comment: Tampermonkey scripts are now stored at Chrome's extension storage. In case anybody needs it: I wrote a python script to extract them. https://gist.github.com/derjanb/9f6c10168e63c3dc3cf0

Comment: Thanks, @derjanb .  Rolled that info into the answer.

Comment: Can someone update this for edge/opera etc?

Comment: @Megachip, it's not that easy, and I personally refuse to touch *Edge*.  This question is specifically targeted to Chrome.  ... If you need to, open a new question (for Opera).

Comment: Any idea where for firefox?

Comment: The Python script didn't work for me. First I tried running it directly on Windows and it couldn't import leveldb even though I had installed it, then I tried running it on Linux using a Windows subsystem for Linux and it ran without errors but gave me an empty output.

Comment: See also [_How to update a userscript's code in Tampermonkey's extension storage directly_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76451614/1744774).