# where are Tampermonkey scripts stored in Safari

Tags: safari, filesystems, userscripts, tampermonkey

Where are Tampermonkey scripts stored in Safari? This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850460/where-are-chrome-tampermonkey-userscripts-stored-on-the-filesystem) point to locations on Chrome, but at the moment, Tampermonkey is also available in Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist within the value of the key "ExtensionSettings-net.tampermonkey.safari-G3XV72R5TC".

You can read the complete content of this key this way:

```
ls ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
defaults read com.apple.Safari.plist ExtensionSettings-net.tampermonkey.safari-G3XV72R5TC
```

At OS X 10.11 and above the file name has changed:

```
ls ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.Extensions.plist
defaults read com.apple.Safari.Extensions.plist ExtensionSettings-net.tampermonkey.safari-G3XV72R5TC
```

Comment: Thanks man! Great product!!! I am trying to dynamically change the content of tampermonkey script. I was hoping that changing this file would also result in changed script. Boy I was wrong.. I am doing some automated tests and it is crucial to me that I can test things out without my intervention. Didn't have any problems in Chrome, but Safari is a pain in my ass. I opened a separate question on this topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378796/dynamically-change-tampermonkey-script-in-safari. Take a look if you have time.