# Tampermonkey script auto-updated and overwrote itself, is it recoverable?

Tags: tampermonkey

I heavily modified a tampermonkey script and removed it's update URL to prevent it from updating. I restarted my PC and the script was overwritten back to the original version from the author when I started chrome back up.

Can I recover the script before it was overwritten? It's at least 12 hours of fairly tedious work that was just lost.

Comment: Probably not.  Do you have a backup of Chrome's folders?  Anyway, snapshot `\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo` and then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11860530/) for a link to a Python tool that can help you poke around the script storage.