# Adding complex HTML using a Chrome content script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am working with Chrome extension's content script to create a complex display that is added on web pages.

I have first tested it directly integrated on a website, but now I need to put it in an extension.

The thing is that the content script API for Chrome only allows to inject javascript. That means that, to inject complex HTML layouts I would need to write it entirely with JS objects, which is long to write, hard to maintain and absolutely not designer-friendly.

I'm wondering if anyone know or can think of a clever way to get a better workflow on this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's relatively easy to add whole web pages by having your content script inject them in an iframe.  Just follow these guidelines:

1. Place the `*.htm` or `*.html` files in your extension's source folder(s).
2. Place any `*.css` and `*.js` files, that the HTML uses, in the extension folder(s) too.
3. Declare the HTML file(s) as resources.  EG:

   ```
   "web_accessible_resources": ["Embedded_Hello_world.htm"]
   ```
4. Do not use any ***inline***, or external server, javascript in your HTML files.  This avoids problems with [the *Content Security Policy* (CSP)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution).
5. This question doesn't cover communicating with the page/iframe, but if you want to do that, it is a bit more involved. Search here on SO; it's been covered many times.

## Example:

You can see this in action by:

1. Creating a new extension folder.
2. Download [jQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js) into it.
3. Create the 5 files as specified below.
4. Load the unpacked extension  (You can see similar steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259212/331508).)
5. Reload this page in Chrome; you'll see the "Hello World" page, embedded at the top.

## Create these files in the extension folder:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version":         2,
    "content_scripts":          [ {
        "js":       [ "iframeInjector.js" ],
        "matches":  [   "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*"
        ]
    } ],
    "description":              "Inject a complete, premade web page",
    "name":                     "Inject whole web page",
    "version":                  "1",
    "web_accessible_resources": ["Embedded_Hello_world.htm"]
}
```

**iframeInjector.js:**

```
var iFrame  = document.createElement ("iframe");
iFrame.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ("Embedded_Hello_world.htm");

document.body.insertBefore (iFrame, document.body.firstChild);
```

**Embedded_Hello_world.htm:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>Embedded Hello World</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link href="HelloWorld.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HelloWorld.js"></script>
</head><body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
</body></html>
```

**HelloWorld.css:**

```
body {
    color:              red;
    background-color:   lightgreen;
}
```

**HelloWorld.js:**

```
$(document).ready (jQueryMain);

function jQueryMain () {
    $("body").append ('<p>Added by jQuery</p>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But the problem is that I need a lot of communication between the page and my script. I think that messaging through an iFrame each UI event (I need to detect mouvemoves, keystrokes etc) is gonna be really complicated.

Comment: Sorry I really don't remember, this was a long time ago. I did find a way to make everything work though. I don't think I went with iFrames though, I was just injecting html in js.

Comment: Suppose if i need to query from background.js from this html. How do i do? I get chrome.tabs.query as undefined? Could you please help?

Comment: @uhs, you need to open a new question for that.

Comment: Is it possible to call a rest api and display the response from the HelloWorld.js/iframeinjector.js on a button click(button inside the iframe)...?

Comment: ATTENTION: This works as of September 2019, but use `chrome.runtime.getURL` instead of `chrome.extension.getURL`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344868/chrome-runtime-geturl-vs-chrome-extension-geturl

Comment: Hello, this only creates a small window at top right. Do you know why?

Comment: Is this method working in manifest v3?

Comment: I can't get the HelloWorld.js file get to work.

Answer (score 5):

This may be better, no external library and no iframe. Is nearly the same as iautomation solution.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
    } else {
        console.log('files not found');
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL("/content.htm"), true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: I got a error: GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
But I am sure I had add the htm in the web source

Comment: @user792883 have you added `"web_accessible_resources": ["content.html"]` to `manifest.json`?

Comment: It say 'files not found'

Comment: Note that the file name is "content.htm" (not "content.html") in the code snippet above.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, that my extension heavily relies on [script templates](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/)

Here's what I did:

- create `templates.html` to store script templates in
- add `templates.html` to the `web_accessible_resources` as in the the above answer^^
- access `templates.html` from `content.js` with xhr and parse with jQuery

#### manifest.json

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["templates.html"]
```

#### templates.html

```
<script id="template1" type="text/template">
    <div class="template1">template1</div>
</script>
<script id="template2" type="text/template">
    <div class="template2">template2</div>
</script>
```

#### content.js

```
function getTemplates(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        $.ajax({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL('/templates.html'),
            success: function(data) {
                var $templates = $('<div></div>').append($.parseHTML(data)).find('script'),
                    templates = {};
                $templates.each(function(){
                    templates[this.id] = this.innerHTML;
                });
                return resolve(templates);
            }
        });
    });
}
getTemplates().then(function(templates){
    console.log(templates.template1); //<div class="template1">template1</div>
});
```