# chrome.runtime.getURL vs. chrome.extension.getURL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What are the differences between [`chrome.runtime.getURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL) and [`chrome.extension.getURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL)?

The documentation implies that `chrome.runtime.getURL` works in both apps and extensions, and [this 2012 announcement](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/7ZCpcIkJ1RM) indicates that some APIs (though *not* `getURL`) have moved from `chrome.extension` to `chrome.runtime`.

What's the point of `chrome.extension.getURL` then, and why isn't it deprecated in favor of `chrome.runtime.getURL`?

Comment: Well they can't remove it immediately but should give a grace period in order not to break thousands of extensions (hello Firefox). Maybe someday it'll be gone but not necessarily as it doesn't seem a burden development-wise.

Comment: I'm not saying it should be removed; but it's not even deprecated. Many Chrome extension API calls are deprecated - search for `deprecated at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs for example.

Answer (score 15):

The `chrome.extension.getURL` is now **deprecated**, you should use `chrome.runtime.getURL`.

From the `chrome.extension.getURL`'s [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL):

> **Deprecated** since Chrome 58. Please use runtime.getURL.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all

Comment: @Treycos why not? OP asked what's the differences, and the main difference is that one is deprecated. P.S it's great piece of info for googlers like myself.

Comment: I thought `extension` refers to extension pages (content scripts, popup scripts), and `runtime` refers to background pages/scripts (including scripts called through `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`). Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Must be deprecated in Firefox too; Error: Please use $(ref:runtime.getURL).

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any, really.

There are some similar functions there with differences, like `.getBackgroundPage`, but in this case there's no effective difference.

And as you said yourself, it's not deprecated either. Why? Maybe just overlooked. `extension` API is older than `runtime`.