# injecting html (inside extension) inside iframe using content script shows blurry

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

For utilising content script advantages, I tried writing html code inside my chrome extension and tried injecting it into a created iframe using content script. It actually works, however it seems blurry (I have tried -`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` - and also if I go to the direct URL of the html page inside the extension (http://chrome-extension://ext_id/views/my_html.html), it doesn't get blurred on the actual html).

```
var elt = document.createElement('iframe');
elt.id = 'my_iframe';
elt.src = chrome.extension.getURL('views/my_iframe.html')
elt.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elt);
```

This is the approach I used. And again, if I go to http://chrome-extension://ext_id/views/my_html.html it doesn't get blurry (please check image at the bottom).

---

So I started investigating what may be causing the issue. 
**First**, I tried to inject live websites into the iframe through src attribute, and they don't get blurry:

```
elt.src = "https://example.com"
```

However, here, one thing I realised for iframe is that all the other URLs that I fetch seem like this in the Inspect Element.

The iframe element is openable and it has `#document` as child which has all the html content as grandchildren

[image]

However, my one looks like this on the DOM that it doesn't open and I don't have `#document` tag either.

[image]

---

**Second thing** I tried was getting the content of the html page using

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('views/my_html.html'), function(data, status){
    // and inject data inside the iframe, however that 
    // caused path errors of separated files such as css and js..
});
```

.. because in my html file, I included files as

```
<link href="/styles/my_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Thirdly**, I tried zooming on the page to see what's happening. When I zoom, it gets blurry and very interestingly, if I open Inspect Element, it gets zoomed it also which doesn't on any iframe or any other website. It seems like I have injected a JPEG image in the iframe; and even inspect element gets blurry inside the iframe

[image]

[image]

If I inject any website into my iframe, even if I zoom in 1) Inspect Element doesn't get magnified, 2) Even if I zoom, it doesn't get pixelated or blurry simply because it's code; however in my case, it's acting like an image.

[image]

It's driving me insane how and why this is happening. Do you have any ideas thoughts what may be causing it or how to overcome this issue?

---

For recreating the issue, you can follow [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15876614/4705339)

Also, I have created a simplified extension for replicating the issue: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y0Dopp1GhU47tWhXgxoGUy3DaDsQDouc

Even an almost empty project, it's blurry:

[image]

However it doesn't on webpage URL to the same html

[image]

Comment: I don't **know** if anything like this would work, but have you tried anything like `-webkit-font-smoothing`? Maybe that's not being included in the iframe? - I'm trying to help but to be fair, this question has made me question why this happens...

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V Yes, I tried `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` but no luck. Also, as I said, if I go to the real path of the extension html, it is very smooth, even if I zoom in. It only looks blurry in the iframe

Comment: Interesting.... Hmmm... I have a gut feeling it's down to the way the browser implements the iframe... But I don't know, I mean you could always create your own JS solution to simulate an iframe? Maybe that could be a better solution? - Obviously it would take time, and it wouldn't answer your question, but it's a work around to say the least.

Comment: Here I have created a [simple demo project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y0Dopp1GhU47tWhXgxoGUy3DaDsQDouc) for showing the issue. You can check too, it's very surprising! Also, what do you mean by "simulate an iframe"?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary, otherwise report on https://crbug.com

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, the issue exists in Chrome Canary too. Submitted the bug report :(

Comment: @senty I mean make some element that's nxn size, and load another page through ajax/xhr into this element... Do you think you could work with that? It was just an idea, doesn't mean it was a good one, lol...

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V ye, probably not as convenient as iframe approach.

Comment: @senty without a doubt not as convenient.. That's why I said in my last response how it's a work around... I appreciate it's not the ideal solution, but it wouldn't be that hard to replicate..

Comment: I'm also having this issue, did you figure out a way to fix this issue?

Comment: For others who are facing the issue, you can star bug here: [https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=826646&q=blur%20iframe%20extension&can=2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=826646&q=blur%20iframe%20extension&can=2)

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?