# Javascript, how do I make it loop this?

Tags: javascript

So I wish to loop the javascript going to a certain page (without actually reloading/clearing console), then execute

```
href="javascript:doSomething(9)"
```

and then loop that by doing a function

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Require more description

Comment: What does this have to do with the console? Also, to load an other page you always have to unload the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it to repeat - you can use an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval).

```
setInterval(function(){
    doSomething(9);
},100); // the 100 is for 100 miliseconds
```

If you want it to repeat without having to wait (that is, block the code) you can use a [normal while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while):

```
while(true){ // will loop forever since the condition is always "true"
    doSomething(9);
}
```

Comment: How do I make it go to a certain link say www.website.com, and reload the page without clearing console? thanks

Comment: You can either load it in an iframe with a parent page (that can refresh the content of the frame) or you need a userscript or extension. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome

Comment: How do I load it in an iframe?

Comment: @YI were you able to solve your issue?