# Sort server-status by cpu

Tags: apache, status

How can I sort apache server-status by cpu load for example?
Can't find any information on how can I sort the log. 
the log is full with parameters and there has to be an option for sorting

```
Srv Child Server number - generation
PID OS process ID
Acc Number of accesses this connection / this child / this slot
M   Mode of operation
CPU CPU usage, number of seconds
SS  Seconds since beginning of most recent request
Req Milliseconds required to process most recent request
Conn    Kilobytes transferred this connection
Child   Megabytes transferred this child
Slot    Total megabytes transferred this slot
```

Answer (score 3):

Sort server-status Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sort-server-status/pagkcebclaolkohmlhhbakhhnipihedo

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own `user.js` script to do the reordering, then include it in the URL you need.  there's more details here: [Manually adding a Userscript to Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome/5259212#5259212)