# Google Chrome extension to change page color

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to crate a plugin which will change background color of specific page say facebook.com on load of page?

I checked samples provided by Google but not able to figure out how to execute script automatically as soon as a user open specific page ( e.g. facebook.com ) in new window or tab.

Comment: What have you tried on coding ? Sounds like you want to make something like userscripts.

Comment: See: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/user-scripts-guide/ http://blog.sarathonline.com/2011/06/writing-your-first-userscript-template.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest add:

```
"content_scripts":[{
    "matches": ["http://www.pageYouWantToModify.com/"],
    "css": ["css.css"],
    "js": ["javasript.js"]
}],
```

The css.css and javascript.js file will run when you open "http://www.pageYouWantToModify.com/"