# How to add my own script in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I changed browser from Opera to FF.
At the beginning I don't want Greasemonkey or other plugin.

I want to add my own JavaScript to some site.
I found this topic:
[Manually adding a Userscript to Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome)

I tried this method with some changes which seems obviously for FF to me,  but it didn't work. It's difficult to debug what going wrong because I don't get any error messages.
Could you give me some advice what I should check?

Comment: Oh do you mean like a bookmarklet? Like if you click on a bookmark it will `alert` the contents of the `<input>` field. Can you tell us what exactly you want to do and I'll show you how to do it without installing Greasemonkey.

Comment: The simplest way: my javascript code should execute immediately after page loaded. I don't have to click anything.

Comment: The only way to do this is to make an add-on or download greasmonkey/scriptish and make a userscript. Do you want help on how to make an add-on? Do you want the SDK way or bootstrap way? (Note: For bootstrap way you will need to change to support multi process later this year)

Comment: thank.
If you have some good links to read, I never say no :D

Comment: Go with the SDK: [How to modify webpages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials#modify-web-pages)

Comment: Google Chrome allows inclusion of scripts directly (although with some limitations). In Firefox, you can use the location hack (passing JS via addressbar) or use an addon that allows inclusion of script (GreaseMonkey/Scriptish). Writing a GM script is a lot easier than writing and maintaining an addon as many aspects are handled by the GM. I suggest you try that first.