# Running your custom java script when visiting a website

Tags: jquery, html

I messing around with inspect element and discovered every time you refreshed the page, the web elements would reset. I started researching how to you console snippets and what preserve logs however with no success I could not find what I was looking for. What I tried doing is change "Jobs" on the stackoverflow website to "Hello" using the following code :

```
document.getElementById('nav-jobs').innerHTML = 'Hello'
```

I saved this as a snippet however I have to manually run this snippet every time I visit the page. Can this be done automatically?

I do know there are extensions such as tamper monkey that let you do this however I want to run my own java scripts. Can someone offer their guidance.

Thanks

Comment: No, thats what things like tampermoney are for - running your own javascript on pages.

Comment: No - this is exactly what TamperMonkey does and why it exists.

Answer (score 4):

You DO run your own javascripts in TamperMonkey (or GreaseMonkey for Firefox) - that's the whole point of the extensions, letting you run your own scripts for pages, to change behavior or alter content and functionality. I fail to see how "running your own" is in any way, shape or form, better than just using what is already available?

So the answer is basically: use TamperMonkey. And if you wanna change CSS as well, run Stylish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tampermonkey (A chrome extension) to do this. [Link to TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)