# Chrome extensions (chrome://extensions) redirect

Tags: google-chrome, redirect

I found some malicious extensions that block your Google Chrome access to chrome extensions so you cannot remove it through Chrome. When you manually type **chrome://extensions** it redirects you to **chrome://apps** or **chrome://settings**.

My questions is does anybody knows how do they do it?

Comment: They are using user-scripts which are executed on every page which is opened in Chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome , also why this question has tag `extjs` ?

Comment: Is there any relation between this question & extjs ?

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In the right top of chrome are extension symbols and you can just rightclick them to remove